# How to specify sqlite database collation

Tags: sqlite, encoding, collation, utf

I've worked with mysql and SQL server. But I'm getting an app made and my app guys don't seem to know much about sqlite.

Like SQL server and mysql, you can specify the collation of sqlite, right? I need my sqlite databases to be in utf-8 encoding so they can store special characters, Japanese, Chinese etc.

How do you do that? Through code, of course.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite uses UTF-8 by default.

Collations are used only to use different comparison algorithms.